# Changing the Filename of a Uploaded Binary File Field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm using **Odoo8**

I have a question I used the `fields.binary` to upload a file/s in Odoo. But when I try to download it the `filename` of the uploaded file is the model name.

Is it possible to change the `filename` of the file?

And second the filters attribute in fields does not work.

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution to this matter/problem, create first a compute field and its function

.py

```
filename = fields.Char('file name', readonly = True,store = False,compute ='legacy_doc1_getFilename')

@api.one
def legacy_doc1_getFilename(self):

    if len(self.employee_number) > 0:
        self.filename = str(self.employee_number) + '_ConfidentialReports.pdf'
    else:
        self.filename = 'filename_ConfidentialReports.pdf'
```

and in XML file just add the attribute file and the field

```
<page string="Legacy Documents">
    <group>
        <field name="filename" readonly="1" invisible="1"/>
        <field name="legacy_doc_1" filename="filename"/>
    </group>
</page>
```

Comment: Good job!, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the following solution sovled it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name')
    image = fields.Binary(string='Image', required=True)
    image_filename = fields.Char(string='Image Filename')
```

in xml:

```
<field name="name" />
<field name="image_filename" invisible="1"/>
<field widget="binary" height="64" name="image" filename="image_filename" />
```

And, here is the result:

[image]