# Odoo 9: How to set the right filename for a custom download field

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-9

I have a custom module where I add custom file upload fields like so:

```
my_upload_2d = fields.Binary(string="Upload 2D")
my_upload_3d = fields.Binary(string="Upload 3D")
```

The problem is that uploaded PDFs or Catia files are downloaded as `.bin` files - how can I see to it that the files are downloaded with the same name they have been uploaded with in the first place?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a filename field for each of your Binary fields to track the names. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835390/changing-the-filename-of-a-uploaded-binary-file-field) for some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a field for the file itself and another field for the file name, ie:

```
description_data_file = fields.Binary('description data')
description_data_file_name = fields.Char('description file name', size=80)
```

And in the xml file:

```
      <group string="File to import">
            <field name='description_data_file' string="Desc file" widget="binary"  filename="description_data_file_name"/>
            <field name='description_data_file_name' string="Desc file" attrs="{'readonly':True, 'invisible':True}" />
       </group>
```

Note that in the xml the binary data field relates to its name using the "filename" parameter.

Comment: Can I do something like this with `pdf_viewer` widget?